# Python Method Based on Argument

Tags: python

I was wondering if the following is possible in Python, and if so any hints on how I might accomplish it.

Let's say I have a function and it calculates answer A for me. The function takes two arguments, B and C. B is a positional argument and must always be provided. C must also be provided but can be either a float or an int (represented by `Arg1` and `Arg2` below). Depending on whether C is a float or int dictates how the calculation in my function is performed. Regardless of the value of C, as long as B doesn't change then A doesn't change.

I've implemented this in code but I end up with a function with lots of `if-elif` statements at the beginning checking the argument types. Was curious if there was a cleaner way to accomplish this.

```
def MyFunction(B, Arg1 = None, Arg2 = None):
    if isinstance(Arg1 , float) is False and isinstance(Arg2 , int) is False:
        # Raise some error here b/c data types aren't correct
    elif isinstance(Arg1 , float) is True and isinstance(Arg2 , int) is True:
        # Raise another error here, must be Arg1 or Arg2 but not both
    elif isinstance(Arg1 , float) is True and isinstance(Arg2 , int) is False:
        # Do something here so that the function uses Arg1 to perform the calculation of A
    elif isinstance(Arg1 , float) is False and isinstance(Arg2 , int) is True:
        # Do something here so that the function uses Arg2 to perform the calculation of A
    # Remainder of function code after this
```

I want the keyword argument names to be different, hence why I used `Arg1` and `Arg2` instead of just `C`.

My inspiration in asking is from some work I've done in the past using Julia. In Julia, I can define a function multiple times and the code will automatically pick the most appropriate definition of my function based on the arguments I pass to it.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you have two arguments `Arg1` and `Arg2` when the description only talks about one argument `C`? I don't understand what you mean by, "I want the keyword argument names to be different."

Comment: The argument `C` has two representations each with its own name (hence the separate keyword arguments). If it is expressed in the first way (corresponding to `Arg1`) the calculation proceeds using method 1. If it is expressed in the second way (`Arg2`) then the calculation proceeds using method 2. If that makes any more sense.

Comment: Is every function declaration in Julia not the same as an `if` statement? Also Python 3.x automatically does the right thing for adding floats and integers. So besides testing for None values, would you not only need an `if` statement to determine to return a float or typecast to an int?

Comment: Since Python doesn't do type-checking on its arguments, it's not necessary to have two different arguments to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the comments says:

> Since Python doesn't do type-checking on its arguments, it's not necessary to have two different arguments to do the same thing.

In this case, you can just use one argument to do it.

code:

```
def foo(B,C):
    if isinstance(C , float):
        # Do something here so that the function uses Arg1 to perform the calculation of A
    elif isinstance(C, int):
        # Do something here so that the function uses Arg2 to perform the calculation of A
    else:
        print("invaild input")
```

**EDIT**:if you really want to change the name of `C` by its type:

```
def foo(B,C):
    if isinstance(C , float):
        Arg1 = C
        # Do something here so that the function uses Arg1 to perform the calculation of A
    elif isinstance(C, int):
        Arg2 = C
        # Do something here so that the function uses Arg2 to perform the calculation of A
    else:
        print("invaild input")
```

Comment: Problem is that I want the name of `C` to be different depending on whether it is a float or int. It says something about how the calculation is performed.

Comment: The name actually doesn't matter in `python`, you can just put the `float` C in `foo` to calculate the result, or you can also put the `int` C in foo, just like use generic type in java or other languages. If you really want to change name of it, I'll edit it.